# How to remove an element within a field in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    _id: "d473ad718f214f158b31d591a97a5ce7",
    name: 'sam',
    keys: {
      q8f3ff57b03940959e1ae4dfe2cb57ad: {
        serviceaccountkey: {
          keyID: 'q8f3ff57b03940959e1ae4dfe2cb57ad',
          status: 'ACTIVE',
          keytype: 2,
        }
      },
      m887f7854adb4907b57903b896bcf6d6: {
        serviceaccountkey: {
          keyID: 'm887f7854adb4907b57903b896bcf6d6',
          status: 'ACTIVE',
          keytype: 2,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose this is a document. How do I remove the first key, with ID "q8f3ff57b03940959e1ae4dfe2cb57ad" from this document? I want the end result to look like:

```
{
    _id: "d473ad718f214f158b31d591a97a5ce7",
    name: 'sam',
    keys: {
      m887f7854adb4907b57903b896bcf6d6: {
        serviceaccountkey: {
          keyID: 'm887f7854adb4907b57903b896bcf6d6',
          status: 'ACTIVE',
          keytype: 2,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $unset:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$unset": {
    "keys.q8f3ff57b03940959e1ae4dfe2cb57ad": ""
  }
})
```

Comment: just tried this and it didn't work

Comment: You need to replace `collection` with your collection name

Comment: yeah I did that

Comment: Also, in the original document, you have 1 excess closing curly bracket on the bottom so it does not closed properly

Comment: This will only work on the first document only, so you might not see the reflection on other documents. Please refer to my answer on this page.

Comment: I think this is not the correct query to remove that element from the document

Comment: @PranavSharan, please pay attention to Akhmad's assertion above. You one excess closing curly bracket in you original document. Ideally, this can be a valid document is mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

This should do if you have many documents matching that ID or key

```
db.collection.updateMany({},{"$unset":{"keys.q8f3ff57b03940959e1ae4dfe2cb57ad":1}})
```

Comment: I tried this and this didn't work

Comment: @PranavSharan, this is your best answer. I inserted your document into my localBD and it works. Unless you are not doing something right. For you to convince us that the document actually exist in the database use this query `db.collection.find({"keys.q8f3ff57b03940959e1ae4dfe2cb57ad":{$exists:true}}).pretty()`